# How to get a custom file not found message

Tags: java, json, api, http, filenotfoundexception

when my code runs and the user puts in a location that cant be found or an input that wont work the system returns a file not found exception with the link. I have no clue how to get that exception message to output to the user instructions on how to get the program to work instead of just saying file not found.

```
  package url_request;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

  public class Test_URL_req {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {




    try {


        String Usercity = "";
        System.out.println("Which city would you like to view");
        Usercity = input.next();




    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+Usercity+",uk&units=metric&appid=10a285fd9251176efb6e230da704ba43";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();




    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine;
     StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
     }
     in.close();



     JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
     JSONObject main_data = myResponse.getJSONObject("main");
     JSONObject wind_data = myResponse.getJSONObject("wind");



     JSONArray weatherarray= myResponse.getJSONArray("weather");
     JSONObject weatherreport = weatherarray.getJSONObject(0);

     String main = weatherreport.getString("main");
     String description = weatherreport.getString("description");



     System.out.println("City - "+myResponse.getString("name"));
     System.out.println("Temp C - "+main_data.getDouble("temp"));
     System.out.println("Weather Conditions- "+weatherreport.getString("main"));
     System.out.println("Weather Summary- "+weatherreport.getString("description")); 
     System.out.println("Wind speed- "+wind_data.getDouble("speed"));
     System.out.println("Wind Direction- "+wind_data.getDouble("deg"));
     System.out.println("Humidity- "+main_data.getDouble("humidity"));
     System.out.println("Pressure- "+main_data.getInt("pressure"));


     } catch(Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }




}



}
```

i want it to output instructions on how to correctly search instead of file not found any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you could explicitly catch a file not found exception

```
catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
```

And then give the user the desired instructions you want?

So where you catch the exception:

```
catch(Exception e ) {
```

add this:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
//Instructions}
catch(Exception e ) {
System.out.println(e);}
```

Comment: thanks for helping but when i put that in and try have the system output a message after in my console it is still just returning file not found and not the message

Comment: Do you get a stack trace telling you on exactly which line it failed and what the exact exception is? If so put a try catch around that line and catch that exact exception and it should work?